# unable to get description from data in react-native

Tags: react-native

i am making flatlist component in which I import a list component which code is below

```
export default function ListItem({ image, title, sutitle }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={image} />
      <View style={styles.tittleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{sutitle}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have created a flatlist component and I have created a dummy data and I pass this in listitems which I import and in this I pass this data as props I get item and image but unable to get description here is my code

```
const messages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "John",
    description: "last seen two days ago",
    image: require("../assets/dummyFemale.png"),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Crish",
    description: "last seen five days ago",
    image: require("../assets/dummyFemale.png"),
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Max",
    description: "last seen 2 min ago ago",
    image: require("../assets/dummyFemale.png"),
  },
];

export default function MessageScreen() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={messages}
      keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ListItem
          title={item.title}
          description={item.description}
          image={item.image}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing description with the use of `sutitle` variable, And you passed description as a `description` variable.

So, either pass description as `subtitle` variable or access as `description` variable.

I have done here by passing as description as `subtitle` variable.

```js
export default function MessageScreen() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={messages}
      keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ListItem
          title={item.title}
          sutitle ={item.description} //change here
          image={item.image}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```